# python understanding array multiplication behavior

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays with shapes:

```
z1.shape
(74L, 1L)

z2.shape
(74L,)
```

why does on multiplication it produces 74x74 size array:

```
z3 = np.multiply(z1,z2)
z3.shape
(74L, 74L)
```

I was expecting an element by element multiplication to achieve z3 of shape (74L, 1L)

How do I achieve the z3 as element by element multiplication of z1 and z2

Comment: [Relevant broadcasting documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [again with pictures](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc).

Comment: The default dimension expansion is `z1 * z2[None,:]`, a (74,1)*(1,74)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `z1*z2[:,None]`.  The extra None index stretches the 1D array into a column array.

Answer (score 1):

Just do,

```
z3 = np.multiply(z1, z2.reshape(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you need to reshape either array:

```
>>> np.multiply(z1.reshape(-1), z2).shape
(74,)

>>> np.multiply(z1, z2[:,np.newaxis]).shape
(74, 1)
```

Unless the shapes of `z1, z2` are identical, the multiplication (or any function for that matter) will be cast as an outer product (`z1 * z1.T`), resulting in the shape `(74,74)` in your case.  In the two examples above,

- `z1.reshape(-1)` casts the first array to the shape of the second `(74,)`;
- `z2[:,np.newaxis]` (or `None` instead of `np.newaxis`) casts the second to the shape of the first `(74,1)`.